# CustomSegmentControl

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have created a custom segment control.I am creating an instance of customSegmentControl and adding it to my viewcontroller.But the delegate method of segment control are not getting fired.Same Code is working in xcode 3.2 but not in 4.2. I am new to ARC .What will be the problem?

```
-(void) ViewDidLoad
{
   CustomSegmentControl *objSegmentControl=[[CustomSegmentControl alloc]init];
   objSegmentControl.frame=FrameForSegmentControl;
  [self.view addSubView:objSegmentControl];
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it..I only have to make the object of my custom segment controller as a class variable rather than local.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you aren't getting delegate code, because you aren't the delegate!

Comment: i didnt get you..would you please elaborate?

Comment: You didn't set `objSegmentControl.delegate = self`, so how can you expect to get delegate methods?

Comment: I Want to override the delegate method setSelectedIndex for that no need to set delegate method. The same code is working in XCode 3.2 but not in 4.2 .May be some issue with Using ARC.Can u help?

Comment: That's not a delegate method, that's an instance method.  Just override it in the subclass.

Comment: I am doing the same and putting the breakpoint in that method but not able to receive the control the that method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the delegates as delegates musthave been implemented in custom class so the operations should be performed there not in your main viewController.

Comment: Using breakpoint i am checking the firing of delegate in the CustomSegmentController,not in mainViewController..